# XSL Transform - как заменить при конвертации знак новой строки?

Tags: xml, xmlparser, xslt

День добрый!

Есть расширение, которое конвертирует данные из XML в CSV.
В полях "S_Street" и "R_Street" присутствуют данные в несколько строк, что конечно ломает формат CSV.

Подскажите пож. как заменить знак новой строки в полях "S_Street" и "R_Street" на пропуск с запятой (" ,").

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:in="com.cisag.app.sales.obj.ShippingOrder" xmlns:sutil="org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="ISO-8859-1" version="1.0" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:key name="deliveryReceipient" match="in:ShippingOrder" use="in:customerData/in:CustomerPartner/in:number" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//in:ShippingOrder/in:UnitLoads">
      <xsl:sort select="in:customerData/in:CustomerPartner/in:number" />
      <!-- 
            <xsl:key name="unitLoad" match="in:ShippingOrder" use="in:UnitLoads/in:number" />
            <xsl:for-each select="in:unitLoad">
             -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(../in:Type/in:code, '-', ../in:number), 1, 26)"/>
      <!-- OrderId -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', '1'), 1, 4)"/>
      <!-- OrderPosition -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ../in:date), 1, 20)"/>
      <!-- CreatedDate -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ''), 1, 20)"/>
      <!-- PlannedDispatchDate -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ''), 1, 20)"/>
      <!-- PlannedDeliveryDate -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', '1300'), 1, 256)"/>
      <!-- DispatchIds -->
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="../in:deliveryData/in:ShippingTerms/in:code='10'">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', 'EXPRESS'), 1, 21)"/>
          <!-- DispatchType -->
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', 'STANDARD'), 1, 21)"/>
          <!-- DispatchType -->
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', '10'), 1, 31)"/>
      <!-- Status -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', '272637665'), 1, 21)"/>
      <!-- Client_id -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ''), 1, 21)"/>
      <!-- User_id -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ''), 1, 31)"/>
      <!-- TrackingNo -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', 'test_test'), 1, 51)"/>
      <!-- PrinterName -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ''), 1, 21)"/>
      <!-- Kennzeichen -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ''), 1, 4)"/>
      <!-- Send_Frankatur -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ''), 1, 21)"/>
      <!-- NachnahmeWährung -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ''), 1, 11)"/>
      <!-- NachnahmeWert -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', in:number), 1, 101)"/>
      <!-- Referenz -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ../in:deliveryPartnerData/in:Partner/in:number), 1, 21)"/>
      <!-- S_ID -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ../in:deliveryPartnerData/in:name), 1, 31)"/>
      <!-- S_Name1 -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ''), 1, 31)"/>
      <!-- S_Name2 -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ''), 1, 31)"/>
      <!-- S_Name3 -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ../in:deliveryPartnerData/in:addressData/in:street), 1, 31)"/>
      <!-- S_Street -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ''), 1, 31)"/>
      <!-- S_StreetNo -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ../in:deliveryPartnerData/in:addressData/in:postalCode), 1, 11)"/>
      <!-- S_Postcode -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ../in:deliveryPartnerData/in:addressData/in:city), 1, 31)"/>
      <!-- S_City -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ../in:deliveryPartnerData/in:addressData/in:Country/in:isoCode), 1, 3)"/>
      <!-- S_Country -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ''), 1, 3)"/>
      <!-- S_Province -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ''), 1, 31)"/>
      <!-- S_Phone -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ../in:customerData/in:CustomerPartner/in:number), 1, 21)"/>
      <!-- R_ID -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ../in:customerData/in:imp_name1), 1, 31)"/>
      <!-- R_Name1 -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ../in:customerData/in:imp_name2), 1, 31)"/>
      <!-- R_Name2 -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ../in:customerData/in:imp_name3), 1, 31)"/>
      <!-- R_Name3 -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ../in:customerData/in:addressData/in:street), 1, 31)"/>
      <!-- R_Street -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ''), 1, 31)"/>
      <!-- R_StreetNo -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ../in:customerData/in:addressData/in:postalCode), 1, 11)"/>
      <!-- R_Postcode -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ../in:customerData/in:addressData/in:city), 1, 31)"/>
      <!-- R_City -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ../in:customerData/in:addressData/in:Country/in:isoCode), 1, 3)"/>
      <!-- R_Country -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ''), 1, 3)"/>
      <!-- R_Province -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ''), 1, 31)"/>
      <!-- R_Phone -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', in:physicalDimensions/in:height/in:amount), 1, 11)"/>
      <!-- Send_Height -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', in:physicalDimensions/in:length/in:amount), 1, 11)"/>
      <!-- Send_Length -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', in:physicalDimensions/in:width/in:amount), 1, 11)"/>
      <!-- Send_Width -->
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="in:actualGrossWeight/in:amount='0'">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', '1'), 1, 11)"/>
          <!-- Send_Weight -->
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', in:actualGrossWeight/in:amount), 1, 11)"/>
          <!-- Send_Weight -->
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', 1), 1, 4)"/>
      <!-- Send_Pieces -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', 1), 1, 4)"/>
      <!-- Parcles -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ''), 1, 256)"/>
      <!-- Send_DTL_Send_Commodity_Code (Warengruppe) -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ''), 1, 11)"/>
      <!-- Send_DTL_Hangers (Bügel) -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ''), 1, 11)"/>
      <!-- Send_DTL_Handlebars (Griffeinheiten) -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('|', ''), 1, 256)"/>
      <!-- Comment -->
      <!-- 
            </xsl:for-each>
             -->
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Пример xml-файла:

```
<documentRecipientAddressData>
  <street>Centroallee 1000 
Einfahrt Parkhaus 7 an der "Alten Waltz" gegenüber Tryp Hotel (H&amp;M sowie C&amp;A zu sehen), vom Ladenhof E über den Serviceeingang zur Fläche EG_1</street>
  <city>Oberhausen</city>
```

Comment: Покажите пример входного xml. Небольшой кусок, именно с полем S_Street.

Comment: Не получается у меня втсавить xml здесь четырьмя пробелами.
Пришлось снова залить:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8P7x0eHO8zNNDQ2d3c3alNMNms/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Я правильно отформатировал? То есть в csv нужно убрать перенос строки между `1000` и `Einfahrt`? Я не вижу никакого S_Street.

Comment: Кстати, в чём смысл `substring(concat())` ? Они по большей части не нужны, имхо.

Comment: да, отформаторовали правильно. 

И да, перевод строки между 1000 и Einfahrt.

S_Street просто в комментариях напротив поля

Comment: substring(concat())

для чего я пока сам не совсем понимаю, если честно.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66433/discussion-between-alexander-gross-and-alexander-petrov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перевод строки это символ с кодом 13. Или сущность `&#13;`. Т.е. все, что нужно, это заменить один разделитель в строке, другим. Если бы длина разделителей была одинакова, то можно было бы использовать функцию `translate()`

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(street, '&#13;', ',')"/>
```

Но т.к. у нас длина различная, то приходится рекурсивно парсить и собирать строки

```
<xsl:template name="replace">
  <xsl:param name="val"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($val, '&#13;')">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($val, '&#13;'), ', ')"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="replace">
        <xsl:with-param name="val" select="substring-after($val, '&#13;')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$val"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:call-template name="replace">
  <xsl:with-param name="val" select="street"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

А для извращений - универсальный шаблон-заменятель

```
<xsl:template name="replace">
  <xsl:param name="val"/>
  <xsl:param name="from"/>
  <xsl:param name="to"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($val, $from)">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($val, $from), $to)"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="replace">
        <xsl:with-param name="val" select="substring-after($val, $from)"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="from" select="$from"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="to" select="$to"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$val"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:call-template name="replace">
   <xsl:with-param name="val" select="street"/>
   <xsl:with-param name="from" select="'&#13;'"/>
   <xsl:with-param name="to" select="', '"/>
 </xsl:call-template>
```